# Создание объекта класса в Java

Tags: java, ооп, полиморфизм

начал разбираться с полиморфизмом и нашел следующий пример:
есть класс `Soldier`, и `General` - его наследник. У первого есть метод `getHealth()`, у второго - `getSlogan()`.

Не понятен принцип создания объекта класса.
Есть следующие строчки кода:

```
Soldier warrior1 = new Soldier();
General warrior2 = new Soldier();
Soldier warrior3 = new General();
```

Как происходит создание объекта. В первой строчке ми создаем объект типа солдат, правильно? Тогда во второй выбьет ошибку, а третья создаст солдата и приведет к генералу? Почему так и когда надо подобное приведение ведь проще сразу создать генерала типа генерал.

И второй вопрос ориентируясь по третей строчке я не могу применить `warrior3.getSlogan()`,только `warrior3.getHealth()` ? А если бы метод `getSlogan()` был в солдате, то такой вызов был бы возможен? И это благодаря полиморфизму?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Давайте начнем с понятия полиморфизм. Полиформизм - это такой свойство в данном случае метода, когда один и тот же метод ведет себя по разному.

Возмем пример из жизни. Есть класс `Животное`. Есть класс `Утка`, которая насаледутся от `Животное`. Есть еще один класс `Собака`, которое тоже наследуется от `Животное`.

Животное это абстракция, где мы можем просто определить метод `Голос()`. Мы его объявим абстрактным или виртуальным. Зависит от языка. Живтоных много, и каждый класс `Утка` и `Собака` будут иметь свои реализации для метода `Голос()`.

Теперь когда мы можем создать `Утку` и `Собаку` и привести их к Живтоному.

Псевдо код будет выглятеть так:

```
Живтоное animals[2];
animals[0] = new Утка();
animals[1] = new Собака();

for (animal in animals) {
    animal.Голос();
}
```

Т.е. при вызове метода `Голос()` мы не знаем реально, с каким объектом мы имеем дело, но можем вызвать именно его реализацию. В этом вся сила полиморфизма.

Теперь ко вопросу про доступные методы. Тип переменной `animal` определяет доступные методы. Именно поэтому ни один метод из класса `Утки` не известен классу `Животное`.

Приведение типов. Это отдельная большая тема. У нас есть возможно приводить типы двигаясь вверх или вниз по дереву наследования. Замечу, что двигаться вниз безопаснее в силу того, что мы знаем текущий тип объекта и можем точно знать от кого он наследуюется. Движение же верх (от абстракции к конкретике) более опасно и именно тут лучше использовать явное приведение типа, что бы подсказать компилятору. Все конечно зависит от языка. В вашем случае приведение к типу генерал невозможно т.к. объекта генерал в принцепе не существует. Есть только объект типа `Солдат`.

Я очень рекомендую для начала разобраться в понятиях объект и тип. Тогда многое в ООП станет более понятным.

Comment: Стоит отметить, что у вас перепутаны направления движения по иерархии типов: традицонно, движение вниз (downcast) - это переход к более детальной реализации, поскольку дерево растет сверху вниз.

Comment: Соглашусь. Просто обычно в UML рисую наоброт просто. Сверху абстракция, внизу детализация.

Comment: Спасибо, учту Ваш совет

Answer (score 6):

Первая строчка создаст экземпляр `Soldier` и присвоит его переменной `warrior1`

Вторая строчка даже не скомпилируется, т.к. создается объект типа `Soldier`, а присваивается переменной `warrior2` более специализированного типа `General`.

Третья строчка создаст экземпляр `General` и присвоит его переменной `warrior3` типа `Soldier`. Все нормально, генерал является солдатом в данной модели.

> Почему так и когда надо подобное приведение?

Непосредственно в данном примере это приведение особого смысла не имеет. Оно лишь демонстрирует, что такое приведение возможно.

В более общей картине мира, у вас может быть где-то еще метод `kill(Soldier soldier)`, и, благодаря наследованию, вы сможете передавать в него и солдат и генералов. Внутри же методу `kill` на аргументе `soldier` будут доступны только те методы, которые объявлены в классе `Soldier`. Говорят, что метод `kill` *абстрагируется* от *деталей реализации* конкретного солдата.

> я не могу применить `warrior3.getSlogan()`, только `warrior3.getHealth()`?  А если бы метод `getSlogan()` был в солдате, то такой вызов был бы возможен? И это благодаря полиморфизму?

Все верно. И да, если бы в классе `Soldier` был аналогичный метод `getSlogan()`, то был бы возможен вызов `warrior.getSlogan()`. Причем, благодаря полиморфизму, был бы вызван именно генеральский `getSlogan()`.

Comment: Тогда такой вопрос, если  использовать третюю строчку, то какие методы будет иметь warrior3 (генеральские в данном случае)? Не совсем разобрался с приведением к типу ?

Comment: Сам объект будет иметь методы обоих классов. Но через переменную `warrior3` будут доступны только методы солдата. Но если вы точно знаете, что `warrior3` - генерал, вы можете выполнить *downcasting*: `((General)warrior3).getSlogan()`.

Comment: Понял Вас, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Полиморфизм позволяет обращаться с объектом наследника так как будто это объект класса родителя.

```
public class A {
    private int var = 1;
    int getVar() {
        return this.var;
    }
}

public class B extends A {
}
```

и где-то в коде:

```
A a = new B();
a.getVar();
```

И это будет работать.

НО! на оборот нельзя:

```
B a = new A();
```

сразу ошибку выдаст
так работать не будет!

То есть указатель от более высокого по генеалогии класса может служить указателем для всех его наследников.

Comment: спасибо за Ваш ответ